# Problems with merging arrays

Tags: php

I have a number of arrays like the one below. These are the result of data retrieved from the database. I need the final array to have the structure mentioned because I need to foreach loop each 'notes' in the successive code. I can't use a for loop only.

```
    array('title'   => 'Testing',
          'content' => 'some text',
          'created' => 'time',
          'tags'    => array(array('title' => 'hello')),
    )
    array('title'   => 'Testing',
          'content' => 'some text',
          'created' => 'time',
          'tags'    => array(array('title' => 'hello')),
    )
```

I want to merge all of these in an array of the format:

```
array(
    array('notes' =>
        array('title'   => 'Testing',
              'content' => 'some text',
              'created' => 'time',
              'tags'    => array(array('title' => 'hello')),
        ),
    ),
    array('notes' =>
        array('title'   => 'Testing',
              'content' => 'some text',
              'created' => 'time',
              'tags'    => array(array('title' => 'hello')),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I've tried many PHP functions but none gave me the result I want. Can someone help me please? Is there a built-in PHP function that can do this? Can someone show me an example.

Thanks.

Comment: no need to use functions, just this is just a simple array assignment on a new one with another format.

Comment: How should I do it then?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you're asking. It's not clear what you mean. Give two complete examples of inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you actually want to do is place each of your array elements into another array with the key `notes` and the value being that of the element (*another array*).

In which case either using `foreach` or `array_map` will do.

```
$newArray = array_map(function($v) { return ['notes' => $v]; }, $array);
```

Or using foreach (the more verbose way)...

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $newArray[] = ['notes' => $value];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid having [0] and [1] before each [notes]?

Comment: Huh? Why are you trying *avoid* that? Perhaps you've formulated the question so poorly that the answer to this question doesn't actually help you achieve what you want. This is possibly the result of asking an X/Y question. Maybe just try asking for what you hoped this would do for you instead?

Comment: This is part of a Laravel task. I'm passing the new array to a foreach loop in the template.

Comment: I've edited the question since it was wrong how you corrected it.

Comment: Wrong how? What you've done is add more ambiguity to the question. Making it harder to understand your underlying problem as well as be able to help you. If you don't have an array of arrays then please explain the context in which you collect the arrays. Otherwise you can just do the guess work yourself and take on the approach of assembling the array manually as already suggested.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that you want `array('notes' => [[],[]])` and not `array(['notes' => []], ['notes' => []])`? Is that it?

Comment: The format in the question is correct. That's what I want.

Comment: Well, the format doesn't actually add up to what you're asking in the question. Nor does it really make much of any sense to do this (*i.e. I can't really understand the added value - hence the X/Y question implication*). In either case my answer remains the same given the lack of clarity in the question I doubt anyone could provide you with any more of a useful answer given the lack of a useful question.

Answer (score 1):

**this is a comment** i want the formatting...

You have asked for an 'array' of 'array entries' where each entry

- is an array
- each array has a key of 'notes' and an associated data array.

I think the 'tags' part of you structure would be easier to use without the extra level of 'nesting'.

Here is the code to create and display the  'wanted' output with the 'tag' entry changed:

```
$wanted = array(
            array('notes' =>
                array('title'   => 'Testing 1',
                      'content' => 'some text 1',
                      'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                      'tags'    => array('title' => 'hello',
                                          'tagFoo' => 'foo' ),
                ),
            ),
            array('notes' =>
                array('title'   => 'Testing 2',
                      'content' => 'some text 2',
                      'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                      'tags'    => array('title' => 'hello',
                                          'tagBar' => 'bar'),
                ),
            ),
        );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($wanted);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [notes] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Testing 1
                    [content] => some text 1
                    [created] => 2015-01-04 15:39:34
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => hello
                            [tagFoo] => foo
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [notes] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Testing 2
                    [content] => some text 2
                    [created] => 2015-01-04 15:39:34
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => hello
                            [tagBar] => bar
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: My aim was to remove the [0] and [1] preceding notes. However, I've found a way to adjust the application to run with a different array. Thanks, it's a good answer though.

Comment: glad you sorted out an approach to the issue that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

one possibilyti is to do:

```
foreach($tags as $key => $note){
    $note["created"] = $created[$key]; //if created is an array
    $note["created"] = $created; //if created is a string
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add the created in the second array. That is not the problem.